# Scan a text file for Strings

Tags: java, file

I'm *scanning* a text file in order to find two sequential words that are equal with my own. If I find them I'll display a window. Βut I can't make it work. I am pretty sure the problem is in this part of the code. I'm pretty novice in `Java` so any help would be much appreciated.

```
public void readFile(String a, String b){
    s=new Scanner("userDataStorage.txt");
    while (s.hasNext()){
        String u= s.next();
        String p=s.next();
        if(a==u&&b==p){
            l.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            l.setSize(400,300);
            l.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use `(a.equals(u) && b.equals(p))` instead of `(a==u&&b==p)`

Comment: What is 'l' in your code and which errors you are getting?

Comment: Variables u and p should be declared outside the while loop to make the program more efficient.

Comment: Post the error that you are getting. As Lone nebula pointed out, use .equals instead of ==

Comment: Well, the l is just a window from another class that I want to pop up if a and u is equal and b and p is equal. The problem is not that the program is too inefficient, but that it simply dos'nt work. When i run from my main I get the window I am looking for, but when I enter the two variables that i use for a and b, I get a bunch of error messages. These are the errors i get:

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException

 at FileMangment.readFile(FileMangment.java:32)
 at Gui$LoginHandler.actionPerformed(Gui.java:39)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)

Comment: And a lot mor, but I was'nt allowed to enter more

Answer (score 4):

If you want to read data from file then you probably should use

```
new Scanner(new File("userDataStorage.txt"));
```

otherwise scanner will just treat `"userDataStorage.txt"` as raw data to scan, not as path to file.

Also if you compare strings then [use `equals` method instead of `==` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/1393766)

```
if (a.equals(u) && b.equals(p))
```

Comment: The OP is also calling `s.next()` twice per iteration of the loop, which is likely to break when it gets to the end of the file.

Comment: @HenryKeiter I assume that OP stores in file Strings in pairs so if `hasNext` returns true then it also mean that there are two more elements. But if he doesn't then you are absolutely right.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to compare *Strings* use

```
a.equals(p) && b.equals(p)
```

or

```
 a.equalsIgnoreCase(u) && b.equalsIgnoreCase(p)
```